# Opencart export tool choking around 12,000 products

Tags: php, export-to-excel, opencart, phpexcel

I am using [this extension](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=17) to perform export/import for the product database on [our website](http://ciamedical.com/). The site is pretty snappy--loads quickly, on a killer server, everything functions flawlessly except for the product import/export.

Everything worked fine up until the point where we had about 12,000 products in the catalog. Now, it appears that product import works fine. Problem is, exporting products is choking. Here's what happens... click export, hangs for about 10-12 minutes (during which time the site goes down, unless I kill the process via CLI), then goes to a "page not found" error, the same link the admin export function was accessing.

**Technical data & stuff I have tried or considered...**

- Import export code may be downloaded [here](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/download&extension_download_id=323615). Opencart is based on MVC framework, so controller and model are obviously the important files to look at.
- I have upgraded the original plugin to utilize the absolute latest version of [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) and Pear library, with OLE and Spreadsheet extensions--both utilized by the import/export module.
- PHP.ini settings are maxed out--allowing up to 8 gigs of RAM, post_max_size, max upload, and all other settings are pretty much maxed out. Server is running dual quad-core Xeons with a number of SAS hard drives, with an average processor usage around 3%. So, it's not the server, and unless I'm missing something, it's not the php settings that is the root of the problem here.
- There are no errors being thrown in the error log that would indicate any specific problems in the code. Just the fact that it was working before, and now locks up while exporting products when more than 12k products are in the DB.
- I have tried repairing the product tables, optimizing the database, and re-installing the base Opencart framework.

I realize this is a pretty general question here, but I'm at my wits end. I am not going to code a custom import/export module from scratch to nail this problem down. Simply hoping that someone might be able to shed some light (extension author has not been able to answer this issue). I've picked this thing apart from top to bottom and can't find any reason why it wouldn't be working the way it should.

Comment: Does the "choking" happen around 30 seconds mark? Are there any errors in apache log? Have you enable dull error reporting?

Comment: Error reporting is set to all, so if there was an error popping up it would have shown. It hits the choking point around 10-12 minutes, which is aggravating, because it would be much nicer if it hit around 30 seconds instead :)

Comment: Here's an idea: export to CSV file. Excel can read it too.

Comment: You know, I thought of the same thing. Not a bad idea, but would need to modify the script to import the multiple sheets separately, no? This wouldn't be very difficult I imagine...

Comment: Seems there is already a solution for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384052/many-different-csv-documents-to-be-convertered-to-one-excel-document

Comment: Linux box, so, as far as I'm aware vbs would not be an option. I see your point, of course. If efficiency were the issue (which it is), I would be fine parsing multiple CSV files separately. I like the idea, and will try to implement this.

Comment: There are CSV import/export tools available in the extension store for a fee if that's what you want/need to do. I think there are a couple of free ones as well though not sure on the quality of those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simpler than I would have ever imagined.

Export tool that actually works for large product databases (and of course, exports to CSV).

Here is [the link](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=5664).

Answer (score 0):

10 - 12 minutes is a relatively short time for larger imports. I've seen them last over 45 minutes before now on dedicated servers with plenty of RAM. It had the same problem as yours where the site became totally unresponsive during the upload/import. The problem is the inefficiency of using excel and decoding all of the values from the saved excel sheet. I did actually custom code an efficient version for a client back on 1.4.X that did this but it was by no means pretty and took quite a lot of debugging. The actual export was massively inefficient too just joining all the tables together and taking up vast amounts of memory (over 1.8GB if I remember correctly). This too was massively reduced by selecting smaller duplicated rows and parsing them separately then inserting them back into arrays for the export data. It was quite incredible at just how much faster this was

Comment: So what you're saying is, eliminate the unnecessary tables from the export/import if they are all going to be the same data anyway? Take a multi-sheet excel file, get it down, and minimize the code of the export/import script? Or is there something else I'm missing here?

Comment: The biggest part of the import slow speed is the fact its excel and needs parsing with some intensive CPU not the tables as such. They're more of an issue for the export

Comment: But it just doesn't make sense why it wouldn't just take longer. It's as though it is timing out. Even if it is an inefficient script, shouldn't it just take longer to execute?

Comment: Yeah it should eventually parse it all through. If it is timing out then you should have a record of it in your proper php error log (not the one from opencart). The same could be said for if it was maxing out your memory